# MicrosoftAccess/Excel: How do I update a field in one table to match a field in another table if 2 fields across those tables match?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm an intern working on some data cleansing and I've reached am impasse with some of the data I'm working with.

I'm attempting to move matching Serial and Part numbers from one table to the new table, but only if 2 other fields match across tables.

Basically:

```
I want [GPFixedAsset].[OasisPar] to update to [OasisFixedAssets].[PartNumber] 
if [GPFixedAsset].[OasisLink] = [OasisFixedAssets].[SysIDOasis]
```

And then the same for the serial number:

```
[GPFixedAsset].[OasisSer] to update to [OasisFixedAssets].[SerialNumber] 
if [GPFixedAsset].[OasisLink] = [OasisFixedAssets].[SysIDOasis].
```

I'm still trying to learn SQL but it's a little confusing right now.

If it can be done in Excel with a formula that would be great. But if I can run two separate queries to update my table so I can export it back to excel that'd be awesome.

EDIT:
Thanks everybody for the answers. I ended up sorting it out by running a select query to find all the fields that matched between the OasiLink and SysIDOasis, then ran separate update queries based on the that query to update the fields to the correct value.

Comment: It might also be possible using Formulas in Excel, it would only act as a reference and not copy value from 1 place to another. Definitely possible using VBA in Excel, and SQL in Access. What exactly are you looking out for?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Format:

Unfortunately I can't comment so I have to use an answer but I would suggest using  [Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx) and a [Cursor](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) to achieve this through SQL.

`Cursor` is a loop which will read each row one by one. Within the Cursor you can store the value into the Variable and compare them. If they match then run the Update script:

```
DECLARE @Value1 = NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Value2 = NVARCHAR(50)
```

Each time you went through the cursor it would update each value

So the update statement would be something like

```
Update [GPFixedAsset]
Set [OasisPar] = @Value1 
Where @Value1 = Value2
```

I had to do something similar the other day so this is the best way I did it.

Hope it helps,
Sam